# UIViewController <UIKeyInput> shows keyboard when popping back

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, keyboard

I have a `UIViewController` subclass that implements `UIKeyInput`. This is a full screen view controller that needs to take control of the keyboard. I am showing the keyboard depending on subviews with `resignFirstResponder` and `assignFirstResponder`.

`canBecomeFirstResponder` is overridden to return  `YES`. However, when another view controller is popped off the stack (i.e. back button pressed) back to this view controller, the keyboard appears and then disappears. Almost as if it calls `canBecomeFirstResponder`, see yes, shows the keyboard, then `resignFirstResponder` is called in `viewDidAppear` which hides the keyboard.

Is there a way to keep the keyboard hidden until `assignFirstResponder` is called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override `-isFirstResponder` and return `NO` (or some custom, conditional logic) from that method in order to prevent such keyboard appearance:

```
- (BOOL) isFirstResponder {
    return NO; // or something else, depending on conditions
}
```